# Hosted Site on IIS7 loads whenever I create a new website project on Wamp server

Tags: sql-server, apache, iis-7, wamp, wampserver

**How can I prevent an old Hosted site on ISS7 from loading up whenever I type the web address to a new site on my Wamp Server?**

I just installed Wampserver on a Windows 2008 Server that was already hosting a wesbite of mine via IIS. So I changed the port number of the Wampserver to port 81 instead of 80, and installed it to the Wamp server with no issues.

However, as soon as I created a new project on my Wampserver, and attempted to test the new page; for some reason only the old hosted website on IIS7 loads up. This problem seems to repeat no matter what new projects I create on wamp.

I'm a novice at Wamp so if anyone know how to solve this problem please let me know, and if you can be as detailed as possible. Thank you!

Comment: You have to use the port number if you change it from 80. so use `localhost:81/folder`

Comment: Where do I change to it localhost:81/folder. Can you tell me the path or instructions to fix it?

Comment: In the address field of your browser.

Comment: Yes, you have to enter it manually **every time** in the browser address bar, thats why changing the port number can be such a pain.